# How to make a discord command with arguments?

Tags: image, discord, arguments, command

I'm new to the coding and stuff and I want to know if there are any tutorials or pages where I can solve this:
I want to make a discord command that looks like this `!acz map Lasius flavus` where: `!acz`  is the prefix, `map` is the command and `Lasius flavus` are two arguments.

Bot responds with message that is a link with the two arguments, that should look like this: https://antmap.coc.tools/images/Lasius.flavus.png
that means that we get a reply on discord that is a picture.
I want to be able to type in my discord `!acz map Genus species` - and bot responds with `https://antmap.coc.tools/images/Genus.species.png` where the first letter of Genus is capital, just like in the example.

I'm adding a picture with what I have in mind, where `?` is prefix, `map` is command and `Lasius flavus` is Genus species
(no, I already asked for the code)
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please refer to the [official Discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) for help on commands. There are countless videos on YouTube as well, where you can learn how to code commands which will do exactly what you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command(brief="Za map napiš Rod a druh a vyskočí ti mapa výskytu!")
async def map(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.channel.send('https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}.png '.format('.'.join(args)))
```

this was the way and reading through https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace helped me! eve tho I didn't use the replace()! I just had to change a few pieces in a code that sent noarguments and arguments:

```
@bot.command()
async def map(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.channel.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))
```